# Meteor - trigger window resize on document load

Tags: meteor, resize, onload

I'm newbie in Meteor looking for jQuery alternative of

```js
$(window).load(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        // do stuff
    });
});
```

I'm wordering what is the right way to do this in Meteor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abigail Watson has a good write-up on this [in her Meteor Cookbook](https://github.com/awatson1978/meteor-cookbook/blob/master/cookbook/window.resize.md).

I'm on my phone in a crowd right now so have to be brief, but basically her solution uses

```
Meteor.onStartup()
```

a session variable, and a helper attached to the first-loaded template.